# How can I mock a Void return type in Scala with Mockito?

Tags: java, scala, mockito

I have a scala project with a Java dependency.  I want to execute some code when a call is made to a java method that returns Void (specifically, I want to complete a future when this method is called).  Is there any way to do this?  The following compiles but throws an exception at runtime:

```
  val startLF = SettableFuture.create[Unit]()

  when(mockConsumer.start).thenAnswer(new Answer[Void]() {
    override def answer(invocationOnMock: InvocationOnMock): Void = {
      startLF.set()
      Void.TYPE.newInstance()
    }
  })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can ascribe `null` as `Void`, e.g.

```
def foo: Void = null
```

So in your example, you can replace `Void.TYPE.newInstance()` with `null` or `null: Void` to be clearer.

Answer (score -1):

You could add an implicit `Unit -> Void` conversion:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
implicit def unitToVoid(u: Unit): Void = null
```

Then anything that returns `Unit` can be used in a place that expects `Void`, e.g.:

```
def foo: Void = println("")
```